# Backup whole F5 bigIP configuration and save as file

Tags: bash, backup, f5, big-ip, tmsh

I'm trying to export my current F5 bigIP configuration into a file and later create a replica of the same bigIP with that configuration.

[This reference](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13132#BackingUp) mentioned following this:

**Create the UCS archive file by using the following command syntax, replacing  with the full path to the UCS archive file:**

```
tmsh save /sys ucs <path/to/UCS>
```

I logged in to my bigIP, but when trying this, it gives me error. What is the problem? How to fix it?

```
Syntax Error: "ucs" unexpected argument
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the syntax within the TMSH shell just like on a Cisco.  Just enter `tmsh` and then type `save` and hit `?` from there you can also use tab to complete the command.

Comment: `Modules:
  sys  General system configuration
`

Answer (score 0):

This command should save a dated ucs file to your /var/local/ucs directory.

`[yourbigip] # tmsh save sys ucs "$(date | tr -d ':' | tr -d )".ucs`

You can always find additional help at https://devcentral.f5.com.